# Showing loading screen in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one part of my site which takes a long time to load. This makes the site appear to hang when you click a link to this. I know it will happen and so it's fairly mean to not tell the user that they are waiting for something which is meant to happen. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to render some kind of loading screen with a simple loading spinner animation to show the user that the server is working. I was thinking of creating a new view which would automatically redirect to the actual view but I thought this would be a bit messy. Any better ways?

Comment: Check [this](http://jh3y.github.io/whirl/). The page can show the loading spinner and then you can use javascript to remove the spinner after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: Problem is I have no idea how this would be properly done in RoR.. Controllers seem to pause all rendering until they complete.

Comment: You're going to have to use some JavaScript here.

Comment: That's not an issue. I'm just having trouble making RoR render anything before it finishes it's controller function..

Comment: You are trying to solve typical issue with wrong approach. 

You can use web sockets for that, but I very strongly don't recommend do this. Use javascript.

Comment: Again, I have no trouble using Javascript. It's just the fact that I can't render anything at all before the controller finishes. If I was able to render a site with some Javascript on it and then hook my function up with a callback that removed it then that would be fine. But I have no idea how to, or if it's even possible to do this in RoR.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @PMunch?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Huw

Comment: I think i've worked it out - will write up what I've done and post it. Hopefully it'd be useful

Comment: That would be great! Someone down the line might find it useful.

Comment: @Huw I think I'm that someone...has anyone solved?

Comment: My bad, @MicFin, I will indeed write up my work around here - though it may not be best practice, it might have to wait a few more days though. If you need something sooner, see if you can slip me some contact details I'll show you the code I'm using.